# Attempting to write a String constructor to handle static char * such as "Hello World"

Tags: c++

I've got a String class. Recently, I found the poor thing couldn't handle:

```
String string = "Hello World";
```

I immediately decided to rectify this by adding a constructor. However, the exact parameter eludes me:

```
inline String(const char[] str) : Array(str, sizeof(str) / sizeof(char)) { }
```

generates the following error: "error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'str'"

What I'm thinking is that since it's a static char * literal, it isn't meant to be passed to a function. But, I don't actually know.

Thanks. (To reassure - Any array passed to Array will promptly be copied, not stored)

Comment: Does it work if you change the signature to   inline String(char const* const str)? Or just  inline String(char *str)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest would be to take `const char*` as the parameter. Then use `strlen` to find the string length, then allocate `len+1` characters using `new` and use `strncpy` to copy the string to the newly allocated memory. BTW, any specific reason not to use `std::string`?

Comment: Its ok for learning purpose, for production code it doesn't make sense to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: It's a good thing I'm trying to learn C++, then. :) Thanks. :)

Comment: Why not just use strdup? This way you can init the ptr in the initializer list.

Comment: @RedX: But then you need to use 'free` and if there are other constructors for `String` class which does `new` the code will be real mess.

Comment: @Asha Ah! now i see what you mean, yeah you should definitely stick to `new` or `malloc` not mix both. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You not need to use sizeof(char) - according to standard of C++ sizeof(char) always equals 1.

Answer (score 0):

This particular error is generated because the square brackets `[]` should go after `str`, not after `char`. Change this and the error should disappear.

However, I don't think your calculation `sizeof(str) / sizeof(char)` will work, because when an array is used as a parameter, you lose the information regarding the length of the string. It only work if you are using the original array. The calculation you perform will be equivalent to `sizeof(char *) / sizeof(char)`, which will not reflect the size of the string. Instead, do as Asha says and use `strlen` and `strcpy`.

Comment: I sorta figured that when I checked a breakpoint and "count" was equal to 4. Thanks, though. :)